# Implementation of IHttpExceptionStatusCodeFinder is not working

Tags: c#, abp

Implementation of IHttpExceptionStatusCodeFinder is not working after following the below link documentation.

Actually I was trying to send 401 to client always when we throw AbpAuthorizationException from controller.

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Exception-Handling#http-status-code-mapping

```
public class CustomException : IHttpExceptionStatusCodeFinder
{
    public CustomException()
    {
    }
    
    public HttpStatusCode GetStatusCode(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception is AbpAuthorizationException)
        {
            return HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
    
        return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
}
```

Have tried above code when throwing AbpAuthorizationException it is still sending 403 as User.IsAutheticated is true and above code not getting fired.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to override the DefaultHttpExceptionStatusCodeFinder as mentioned in the documentation.

```
if (exception is AbpAuthorizationException)
{
    return httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated // change this
        ? HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
        : HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
}
```

Full source code of this class you can find here:
[DefaultHttpExceptionStatusCodeFinder](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.AspNetCore/Volo/Abp/AspNetCore/ExceptionHandling/DefaultHttpExceptionStatusCodeFinder.cs#L14)

For override you need to add this attribute

```
[Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
```

You can find more information about this topic in the documentation [Customizing](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Customizing-Application-Modules-Overriding-Services)